# UITableView Cell not showing UITableView(KPDropDown) placed on custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am working on one application and want to show dropdown list on tap of button. Now those buttons are placed on `UITableViewCell` which means indirectly `UITableView`. 
I am using `KPDropDown` for showing dropdowns on app. Now when I tap on button to open dropdown, its not showing its proper frame.

Please refer screenshot attached.
[image]

And help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

In KpDropMenu.m -->didTap ---> [self.superview addSubview:self.tblView] replace with [self.superview.superview.superview addSubview:self.tblView] then you will need to adjust the position accordingly.

Comment: Did you test this? It is a direct copy from a similar issue on the projects' GitHub page https://github.com/KrishnaPatell/KPDropMenu/issues/8

Comment: Yes, its mine comment.